# CGAT - installation - setuptools version

Tags: python, setuptools

I trying to install CGAT from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CGAT/0.2.3 on Redhat 6.4.

I tried to install it with 'pip install cgat' and I got:

```
 Version detected: 0.6
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/CGAT/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
        "the CGAT code collection requires setuptools 1.1 higher")
    ImportError: the CGAT code collection requires setuptools 1.1 higher
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Version detected: 0.6
```

when I run:

```
pip show setuptools
```

I get:

```
---
Name: setuptools
Version: 14.0
Location: /path/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-14.0-py2.7.egg
Requires:
```

Why python cannot see the right version of setuptools??

I also tried to install CGAT with:

```
./install-CGAT-tools.sh --cgat-scripts --lite --location /path
```

When I tried to run, for example:
cgat bam2bam --version

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/envs/cgat-scripts-lite/bin/cgat", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/path/envs/cgat-scripts-lite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CGATScripts/cgat.py", line 126, in main
    module = imp.load_module(command, file, pathname, description)
  File "/path/envs/cgat-scripts-lite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CGATScripts/bam2bam.py", line 143, in <module>
    import CGAT._bam2bam as _bam2bam
  File "calignmentfile.pxd", line 74, in init CGAT._bam2bam (scripts/_bam2bam.c:4385)
ValueError: pysam.calignmentfile.AlignmentFile has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I tried to reinstall pysam again with no success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from cgat group the full answer in: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cgat-user-group/2qErNah5vrg

For the first problem, I did not manage to fix it. 
but for the second I downgrad pysam==0.8.1 and it fix the problem.